# Prove that operator on $\Bbb R^2$ of counterclockwise rotation is isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

An operator on $\Bbb R^2$  of counterclockwise rotation (centered at the origin) by some angle is an isometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator is $L(x) = (x_1 \cos \theta-x_2 \sin \theta , x_1 \sin \theta+ x_2 \cos \theta) =   Q x$, where
$Q = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$. Since $Q^T Q = I$, we have $\|L(x)\|^2 = \langle Qx , Q x \rangle = \langle Q^T Qx , x \rangle = \langle x , x \rangle = \|x\|^2$, hence
$L$ is an isometry.

Comment: The beauty and hardness of basic linear algebra. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

$$|(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta,y\cos\theta-x\sin\theta)|=|(x,y)|$$

Work out the algebra and cancel the $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$ and you're there.

Answer (score 0):

You rotate around the origin: the distance from the origin is preserved. The distance from 2 arbitrary points, which we now will see as vectors, is preserved because the length of the 2 vectors and the angle between them are preserved.